# vector analysis, area of surface

Tags: vector-analysis, area

I am trying to solve this question:

'Obtain the surface area of part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ contained within the cone
$z \tan \alpha= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ where  $0 \le \alpha \le \pi/2$.

Explain how you can get the area of the hemisphere using this result.'

I obtained the normal to be $(x,y,z)/a$ and tried to integrate:
integration of 
$$
ds= \int\!\!\!\int a/z \,dx \,dy
$$. 
However I do not know how to obtain the limits. Does anyone know how to solve the problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recast into spherical polar coordinates. Since the cone is aligned with the $z$ axis (*we can always rotate so it is*) we know it will intercept the sphere on a circle of constant $z$. We know that on this circle the radius $a$ forms the hypotenuse and $z$ the adjacent of a right angle triangle, as shown in the diagram below:

[image]

The angle that the cone makes with the $x$ axis is precisely $\alpha$ because the slope of this line is $\tan(\alpha)$. Therefore the adjacent angle is given by $\Theta = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(\tan(\alpha)) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha$,

Now we can form the integral in spherical polar coordinates with nice easy limits

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\Theta a^2 \sin(\theta)\, d\theta\, d\phi$$

which after evaluation and minor simplification gives us that the surface area is

$$2\pi\, a^2(1-\sin(\alpha))$$

Another way to arrive at this answer is to consider the surface area of the whole sphere multiplied by the ratio of the [solid angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) formed by the cone to the whole sphere.

Comment: can you please explain further how you arrived at the angle π/2−α?

Comment: Imagine taking a 2d slice through the cone, one edge goes of from $z=0$ with a gradient of $\tan(\alpha)$ we call the angle between this line and the $z$ axis $\Theta$. It can then be arrived at with basic trig.

Comment: @user120768 I just added a diagram to help visualize what I was trying to explain. Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. If this solves your question can you consider accepting the answer (it gives both of us points ;-) )

Comment: I used the same method but the  answer I obtained was 2πa^2(1−cos(α)) and it matched the solution in my book. I think you might have a slight mistake in the limits of theta

Comment: Apologies, you're correct. The answer I have is if the cone is defined by $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \cdot \tan\alpha$ but in your question it's $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} / \tan\alpha$ so the angles are swapped which gives us $\cos(\alpha)$ in the answer. I should read more carefully.